# How to bind to a property on a page from inside a data template (WinUI 3)?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, winui-3

I am trying to bind to a property of the page from within a `DataTemplate`. According to the [Databinding in Depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) article, every data binding has a `DataContext`. This `DataContext` defaults to the `Page` itself, and is inherited by child elements. A `DataTemplate`, however, overrides this `DataContext`, thus changing the context for all elements *within that data template*.

How can I bind to a property on the `Page` itself *from within that data template*? In the example below (commented), I want to bind a `TextBlock` Text property to a property on the page `MyPage.MyName` from within the `DataTemplate` of a `ListView`.

Is this possible with `x:Bind` or will I need to use `Binding`? How do I do this?

MyPage.xaml.cs :

```cs
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    // ...
    public string MyName { get; set; }

    // MyCar is a class with a Name and Color property (both strings).
    public ObservableCollection<MyCar> Cars { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

MyPage.xaml :

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <!-- The DataContext for the binding here is the Page itself (MyPage). -->
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyNameTextBlock"
               Text="{x:Bind MyName}"></TextBlock>

    <!-- The DataContext for the binding to the ItemsSource is also the Page itself (MyPage) -->
    <ListView x:Name="MyCarsListView"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind Cars}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- The DataTemplate changes the DataContext, overriding the default. -->
            <!-- The new data context is now the specific item in the collection from the ItemsSource property in the ListView. -->
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyCar">

                <StackPanel>
                    <!-- The DataContext for these two bindings is now the specific Car. -->
                    <TextBlock x:Name="CarNameTextBlock"
                               Text="{x:Bind Name}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="CarColorTextBlock"
                               Text="{x:Bind Color}"></TextBlock>

                    <!-- This DOES NOT WORK. I want to refer to the MyName property on MyPage (a different DataContext). -->
                    <TextBlock x:Name="OwnerTextBlock"
                               Text="{x:Bind MyName}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877265/how-do-i-bind-to-a-property-on-the-viewmodel-from-inside-a-datatemplate) seems to have a similar problem, but the answers are not clear on the working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

1. Name your page using `x:Name`.

```xml
<Page x:Name="RootPage" ...>
```

2. Bind your code-behind property *MyName* using `Binding`, `ElementName` and `Path`.

```xml
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MyCar">
    <!-- Doesn't compile.
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind MyName, Mode=OneWay}" />
    -->
    <!-- Doesn't compile.
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind RootPage.MyName, Mode=OneWay}" />
    -->
    <!-- Compiles but the binding fails and doesn't work.
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RootPage.MyName}" />
    -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=RootPage, Path=MyName}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Since you are using `ListView` the code above works but if change your mind and want to use `ItemsRepeater` instead, it won't work.

[ElementName bindings don't work inside ItemsRepeater DataTemplate #560](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/560)

Comment: I implemented this, and confirmed it works!

Answer (score 1):

A trivial solution to your problem is to name your page, then reference it from your binding:

```
<Page x:Name="RootPage" ...>

<TextBlock x:Name="OwnerTextBlock" Text="{x:Bind MyName, ElementName=RootPage}" />
```

Comment: `ElementName` doesnt seem to exist on `x:Bind`, but otherwise this seems to be the correct way to do it.